# (Bukkit )Is There a Way to do a simple cooldown after doing something, with customizable time and second showing on the item bar?

Tags: function, countdown, minecraft, bukkit

I am doing a minigame plugin for minecraft and i want to make a separated class with a countdown code, and when i need it in  item classes, call it and customize the time for the cooldown.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seconds left are displayed as the Level:

```
public static void startCountdown(int seconds, Player p) {
    int[] countdown = new int[1];
    countdown[0] = seconds;
    final int[] scheduler = new int[1];
    scheduler[0] = Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleAsyncRepeatingTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (seconds == 0) {
                Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTask(scheduler[0]);
            } else {
                p.setLevel(countdown[0]);
            }
            countdown[0] = countdown[0] - 1;
        }
    }, 0, 20);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there are two problem, the first one, is that i want to set a countdown for every player separately, and the second one, is: How can I set the custom time, and call this?

Comment: I've edited my code a little bit. You set the time (in seconds) and the Player when you call the Method.

Comment: ok, sorry man had problem with internet connection, yes your answer is right

Comment: I think i've done if I understood what to do :), but if you know the answer can you answer my last question :)

Comment: Yes, now everyone knows that this question is answered